# Count rows in datasource/grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I count the rows in this context before data binding?

This is what I tried but returns always 0 even if there are rows.

```
protected void OnRowDataBoundZeroLevel(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string code = zeroLevelGrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridView firstLevelGrid = e.Row.FindControl("firstLevelGrid") as GridView;
        firstLevelGrid.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'{0}')) SELECT * from [{0}]", code));

        var isData = firstLevelGrid.Rows.Count;
        if (isData>0)
        {
            firstLevelGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actual binding works in the `DataBind` call, so before databind `Rows.Count` always will be empty. If `GetData` returns correct structure, why not check it? Or it returns `IQueryable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer.

Actual binding works in the `DataBind` call, so before databind `Rows.Count` always will be empty. If GetData returns correct `IEnumerable` structure, then you can check it for rows count.

Comment: Well, i wouldn't care about rows count in the `FirstLevelGrid`, and just do `DataBind` without check, because if there are no any records in GetData, then `firstLevelGrid` won't render any rows, so it will be empty anyway.

Comment: I need the data count because I need to use it to set the visibility of the expand button. If there are now data I will set its visibility to false so I do not need to click on each plus to see if there is something in there.

Comment: Then as for me your code is fine. It's ok to have such logic in `OnRowDataBound` method that updates visibility of controls in the row  based on some logic :)